# Azure logic apps total duration is different then sum of actions

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, duration

I'm having issues troubleshooting a failure in  Azure logic app. As you can see in this image [image: this image] Although the total duration of the logic app was more than four minutes, the actions took less than a second each.
How can I get the true breakdown of the four minutes?

**UPDATE:**

I've added logs as Huri advised and now I can see there are 5 minutes between the workflowRunStarted and the first action as seen in the image below
[image: logic apps log]

I still don't understand why this is happening :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Log Analytics workspace" to see more logs of your logic app.

**1.** Create a "Log Analytics workspace" and add "Logic Apps Management" in it, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#install-logic-apps-management-solution).

**2.** Go to your logic app and configure the "Diagnostic settings", please refer to the steps on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#set-up-azure-monitor-logs).

**3.** After completing the configuration above, please wait for a few minutes and then run your logic app serval times for test (The logs in Log Analytics workspace will be a little bit of a delay, I wait for more than 30 minutes. It just show the logs of running instance which run after 30 minutes of the "Diagnostic settings" deployment).

**4.** Go to your "Log Analytics workspace", click "Workspace summary", then click your logic app name.
[image]

You can see more details of the logs in it.
[image]

Comment: Although it's nice to see this summary. It does not help me in troubleshooting a specific logic app. and I still can't understand why the total duration is different then sum of actions

Answer (score 0):

This may be down to Concurrency Control.  If you have your trigger set with a Degree of Parallelism to say 5 only 5 instances can run simultaneously.  Any other triggers that fire will cause the Logic App to have a waiting state.  Technically it has started so the runtime will look worse as a result.